# How to correct words automatically using R?

Tags: r, text, text-mining, spell-checking, autocorrect

I'm working with text mining and before processing the data I need to correct words (English language) that are stored in a .CSV file.

I got what I wanted using python and the TextBlob library. First I step the original file, TextBlob fixes all the incorrect words automatically from the file and in the output, a file is generated with the corrected words.

You can check the python code here:

```
    import nltk
    import string
    import re
    from textblob import TextBlob

    with open(file.csv', 'r') as inFile, open('fileOutput.csv', 'w') as outFile:
        for line in inFile: 
                print (TextBlob(line).lower().correct().strip(), file=outFile) #this function turns all words into lowercase and corrects incorrect words

    print(inFile)
```

Please, could someone please tell me some package in R that does something similar? I haven't found any packages that are able to automatically correct words using R.

Comment: i hope this link will help you :- https://www.r-bloggers.com/automatic-cleaning-of-messy-text-data/

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://www.sumsar.net/blog/2014/12/peter-norvigs-spell-checker-in-two-lines-of-r/